# SwiftUI calling helper functions from another swift class?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have created my app using swiftui. Then I found that sometimes I may need to do some tasks quite frequently. Instead of placing it in the same swiftui files, I think that it should be placed inside another class. However, I wonder how can we call the function of another class inside swiftui? is that I must have new an object to call it?

Comment: That depends, would you show somehow in code what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 4):

As I understand your question:

```
class MyHelper {
    static func helpMe(needHelp: Bool) -> String {
        if(needHelp) {
            return "Help in on the way!"
        } else {
            return "You are ok!"
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let result = MyHelper.helpMe(needHelp: true)
```

You can use `static` or `class` functions inside the helper class, and access to them by '.' syntax. Difference between `static` and `class` functions, that you can override `class` function in the subclass (which is not really needed with helper classes), `static` not.